# Python: creating graph of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, graph

I have this csv file which contains data. It is an upper triangular matrix in the case that the diagonal and all values below the diagonal are zero, the others are positive. I converted this csv file to a list of lists. Now I want to create a weighted graph: the data represents the weights. The element `[1,2]`represents the cost of moving from 2 to 3 ( since python thus works with 0 index). I created the following code:

```
def node_name(row_index):
    return "{}".format(row_index)

def list_to_graph(matrix):
    graph = {}

    width, height = len(matrix[0]), len(matrix)

    for i in xrange(height):
        for j in xrange(width):
            graph[node_name(i+1)] = x = {} #+1 since value stored in 0 is period 1 etc..
            if matrix[i][j] > 0:
                x[node_name(j+1)] = matrix[i][j]
                print x 

    return graph

network = list_to_graph(KS)
```

And my output for `network` is this:

```
{'2': 98.51337155880164}
{'3': 137.34454906953715}
{'4': 218.15546574651833}
{'5': 413.34869005248316}
{'6': 666.2270350272664}
{'7': 797.9587567165102}
{'8': 997.5013223303663}
{'9': 1460.7632960613955}
{'10': 1809.0861562186199}
{'11': 2382.7694940727315}
{'12': 3122.3280376532416}
{'13': 3732.3630313111116}
{'3': 116.63386713570881}
{'4': 163.89156004857298}
{'5': 299.9120227356801}
{'6': 494.5459710128562}
{'7': 602.669896934327}
{'8': 772.343779343747}
{'9': 1174.5900641757353}
{'10': 1482.3497828874088}
{'11': 2002.3755743427757}
{'12': 2683.9053071295357}
{'13': 3226.282117721281}
{'4': 118.23051233212666}
{'5': 195.13714090000937}
{'6': 331.3892836062166}
{'7': 416.3567477286639}
{'8': 555.8153650148515}
{'9': 895.7690408366711}
{'10': 1162.8621204354888}
{'11': 1624.3183600020443}
{'12': 2240.75765138758}
{'13': 2726.092426399202}
{'5': 121.14564913976642}
{'6': 199.35262811793245}
{'7': 261.7443896465671}
{'8': 370.87438374205493}
{'9': 647.7834044240155}
{'10': 873.9878265770668}
{'11': 1274.687357571038}
{'12': 1820.899686075224}
{'13': 2254.490170683136}
{'6': 121.41505558314628}
{'7': 162.32152799962728}
{'8': 241.32264172194883}
{'9': 454.7689172019634}
{'10': 639.9443076565304}
{'11': 978.7563372780104}
{'12': 1452.6482404550877}
{'13': 1835.5851145271822}
{'7': 137.9617892866049}
{'8': 187.69120234649745}
{'9': 337.58951574619493}
{'10': 481.76469790892816}
{'11': 758.0610269947168}
{'12': 1158.4981002850616}
{'13': 1490.7795743195686}
{'8': 129.8725161849312}
{'9': 216.76064960278163}
{'10': 320.2603703890388}
{'11': 533.752727340574}
{'12': 860.0572933975961}
{'13': 1141.477984317925}
{'9': 114.05888494278352}
{'10': 177.90262985630054}
{'11': 328.67436159661725}
{'12': 580.4970486714274}
{'13': 810.9236051238793}
{'10': 148.39898272917065}
{'11': 237.27051271033224}
{'12': 414.64410623056614}
{'13': 594.141919165608}
{'11': 142.1396818337205}
{'12': 245.88258807317249}
{'13': 374.8852846509406}
{'12': 133.65770253881522}
{'13': 213.47882754657903}
{'13': 151.28090209111411}
    {'11': {'13': 213.47882754657903}, '10': {'13': 374.8852846509406}, '12': {'13': 151.28090209111411}, '1': {'13': 3732.3630313111116}, '3': {'13': 2726.092426399202}, '2': {'13': 3226.28211772
1281}, '5': {'13': 1835.5851145271822}, '4': {'13': 2254.490170683136}, '7': {'13': 1141.477984317925}, '6': {'13': 1490.7795743195686}, '9': {'13': 594.141919165608}, '8': {'13': 810.92360512
38793}}
```

As you can see, it only contains the values of the last "column" (column 12, period 13) of my "matrix". It does not store values for all the other combinations, e.g. 4 to 7 or 1 to 2 etc. etc.

Edit: I added the statement `print x` in the code and the output it produced. The first numbers 2-13 correspond with the weights for node 1 to node 2-13 respectively, then 3-13 correspond with the weights for node 2 to node 3-13 etc etc.. It prints all of this, but only 1->13, 2->13, ... , 12->13 weights are added to the final graph?

Edit2: After the suggestions of Code-Apprentice, my code looks like this:

```
def list_to_graph(matrix):
    graph = {}

    width, height = len(matrix[0]), len(matrix)

    for i in xrange(height):
        for j in xrange(width):
            graph[i+1] = {}
            if matrix[i][j] > 0:
                graph[i+1][j+1] = matrix[i][j]
                print graph[i+1][j+1]

    return graph
```

Again, all the values of the matrix are printed as before, but just the last 'column' is stored in the graph?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is wrong in my code? How can it occur that all the other values are not stored in the graph?

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger or add `print()` statements to figure out what is happening in your code. Debugging is a critical skill for all programmers.

Comment: When I add `print x` at the end of `list_to_graph`, then the output for network is first, all values in the "matrix" are printed, but why are they then not all assigned to the graph? I'm not familiar with debuggers, I'm new to python and only have basic skills in programming

Comment: Please edit your code to show exactly where you add `print x`. I understand that you are new to programming. This is exactly why you should learn debugging skills now.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of the variable `x`. You should be able to do `graph[node_name(i+1)] = {}` and `graph[node_name(i+1)][node_name(j+1)] = matrix[i][j]` directly without the intermediate variable.

Comment: Also, what is the reason that you use an integer formatted as a string as the index for your graph rather than just using the integer directly? The later option would allow you to use a list rather than a dictionary.

Comment: I edited the post and I shall try without the `x`.

Comment: Yeah you are right about the index. The code was different before with two numbers in de `node_name` and I changed this, but now I could also use the number directly

Comment: What is "de"? Is this a word?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry! Typing fast, de is dutch for 'the'

Comment: How do you print the whole graph?

Comment: I execute the following: `network = list_to_graph(KS)` and `print network`, where KS is ofcourse my table with data.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code which you posted here. Although on a little closer inspection, I'm not sure what the purpose is. You already have the graph stored in `KS`. Graph simply copies the weights in a 2D list form into a dictionary form. What advantage does the dictionary have over the 2D list?

Comment: I want to find the shortest path and I'm struggling with it and I thought it would be easier to have it defined as a graph? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: A 2D list one of several representations a graph. It's called an "adjacency matrix". In fact the dictionary you are creating is also an adjacency matrix.

Comment: One question: why are you checking `if matrix[i][j] > 0:`? I understand that the weights should be positive. However, you are simply ignoring negative weights rather than printing an error message.

Comment: Because I know I have several 0's in the graph, and I just want to include only relevant edges in my graph. What is the point of printing several Error Messages?

Comment: Edit: I understand in general what the point is, but in this specific case?

Comment: I misunderstood the reason for the `if` condition. A more accurate condition would be `if matri[i][j] != 0:` since you don't want to add zero-weights to the dictionary representation of the graph. This means you won't accidentally ignore erroneous negative weights. You might want a separate condition for negative weights in order to print out an error message since this is very likely a huge problem.

Comment: "Edit: I understand in general what the point is, but in this specific case?" I don't know what you are referring to here. Please clarify.

Comment: At the end of the day, the only advantage of the dictionary representation over the list representation of a graph is that you save memory for very sparse graphs (i.e. ones which have much less than the possible maximum of `n*(n-1)/2` edges). If the graph is complete or close to complete, you do not gain any advantage copying the 2D list to a dictionary. Note that you can implement any graph algorithm with either representation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! May come in use the next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def list_to_graph(matrix):
    graph = {}

    width, height = len(matrix[0]), len(matrix)

    for i in xrange(height):
        for j in xrange(width):
```

The problem is here:
                graph[node_name(i+1)] = x = {} #+1 since value stored in 0 is period 1 etc..

The above line creates a new "row" in `graph` for each **element** of the original matrix rather than for each **row** of the matrix.

Note that you can find problems like this by adding `print` statements in key locations. In this case, you should add `print graph` inside the inner loop (probably at the end) to see what is added to `graph` during each iteration.

```
            if matrix[i][j] > 0:
                x[node_name(j+1)] = matrix[i][j]
                print x 

    return graph
```

Comment: I guess this is exactly what Dmitry Rubanovich says

Answer (score 0):

From a very cursory look, the line

```
graph[i+1] = {}
```

should be before the `j` loop.  So the loop headers should look like this:

```
for i in xrange(height):
    graph[i+1] = {}
    for j in xrange(width):
```

If you don't want entries for empty `j`'s, then you can change it to this (but it will be slower):

```
for i in xrange(height):
    for j in xrange(width):
        graph.setdefault(i+1, {})
```

You might be better off doing something which looks unpythonic in this case, but will be closer to what you want:

```
for i in xrange(height):
    if width > 0:
         graph[i+1] = {}
    for j in xrange(width):
```

Comment: Yes I tried and I get this error: `    for j in xrange(width):
                          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`